# How to select value from the auto suggestion text box?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

[From text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVDdm.png)I have tried many methods to find out the solution but I failed, So please help me regarding this Query

Website:- https://www.goibibo.com/

Inside that website when I am trying to select the value from 'FROM' auto-suggestion text box I failed to select because I am unable to inspect the dropdown, as it was dynamic and it was using some javascript functionality I guess. So please help me with this

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Java with senium, the problem is when writing the xpath

Comment: Show your current code

Comment: I was unable to write the xpath  for selecting that value in from auto suggestion box

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you need XPath for first autosuggest option, try

```
//ul[@id='react-autosuggest-1']/li[@id='react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--0']
```

You can replace `0` with`1` to get second option, `2` - for third option, etc

Comment: But can you please explain me how you inspected that inside li tag

Comment: @SaiVarma you can click on `ul` element programmatically and then print `getAttribute("innerHTML")` of that `ul` to check how list items (suggestions) looks like

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code and instead of sending value hardcoded you can read it through Excel for dynamic.

```html
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Testing {
 public static WebDriver driver;

 @Test
 public void test() throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Driver/chromedriver");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  WebElement fromDropDwon = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']"));
  fromDropDwon.click();
  fromDropDwon.sendKeys("Delhi (DEL)");
  fromDropDwon.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
  fromDropDwon.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  
 }
}
```

Kindly upvote and it matches your expectation.

Comment: I have tried that code but it is not working it is just passing the value to the text box but it is not selecting from the suggestion box

Comment: @SaiVarma put a wait after `fromDropDwon.sendKeys("Delhi (DEL)");` this will also work. It seems you didn't tried complete code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

As it is auto suggesting the content and you want to select the first option from that drop down, you can use selenium's `Keys` enum and you can perform the selection like below :

```
driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputSrc"));
from.sendKeys("Bangalore");

Thread.sleep(3000);
from.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN +""+ Keys.ENTER);
```

If you want to select other option than the first one then you can use the below xpaths to identify that drop down options :

```
//input[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']/preceding-sibling::i/following::ul[contains(@id, 'react-autosuggest')]//li
```

Or

```
//ul[contains(@id, 'react-autosuggest')]//li
```

Below is the code to print all the options from that drop down and to select the particular value :

```
driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputSrc"));
from.sendKeys("Bangalore");

// Giving some delay so that the auto suggestion drop down will appear      
Thread.sleep(3000);
// Fetching options from dropdown
List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id, 'react-autosuggest')]//li"));
// Printing all the option text
for(WebElement element : dropdownOptions) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
// Selecting the first option
dropdownOptions.get(0).click();
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: I have tried this but it is not selecting the value from the suggestion box

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know it is working or not?

Comment: Welcome... By the way, inspecting is difficult in this situation, because the drop down disappears once you move the mouse out from that drop down. But you can see `ul` node in the source so by guessing, we can say that the options are present inside the `li`(Un-ordered list has list). With the help of `//ul[contains(@id, 'react-autosuggest')]//li` locator, we can fetch the text values and we can click on it somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Go to sources tab > Click on the text box > Press F8 or (FN + F8) when disappearing element is available on webpage( By doing this webpage will be switch to debug mode and element can be inspected now).